# Can Pokemon Go run in split screen on Android? Does it then still count as being "active"?

Tags: pokemon-go, android

I just read the question asking if Pokemon: GO! counts as active for the sake of hatching eggs when the screen is locked; the result was that it does not.

So what about if it is split screen? I'd like to do a bit of running (couch->5k style) and was planning to use the app "Run. Zombies!" to do it but it would be great to hatch eggs at the same time.

Edit: Turns out split screen is awkward to enable on my phone, so for the purpose of the question, assume I'm not using any specific method of split-screen or any specific phone. If you know it works for one method/phone, let me know! If you know it doesn't work for another method/phone... let me know that too! :)

Comment: Not an answer, but note that there is a speed limit on egg catching - so depending on how fast you run, it might not count.

Comment: Android natively hasn't Splitscreen afaik, only the custom roms from e.g. samsung provide this feature. I think it comes with Android N (7.0) and you might have it. So my question: What kind of splitscreen?

Comment: Ahh... I'm not really sure what kind of split screen. I just switched from a Samsung phone to the Nexus 6p and thought split screen was standard for android. I never used it very often but it seemed like this would be a good time to use it.
I just looked it up and it seems it needs some tinkering to make work on my phone... I'll edit the question.

Comment: I don't remember 100% but I think they said on the Android Central Podcast (the special episode about Pokemon GO) that Android N is not supported yet, thus split screen is likely also not supported yet.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't sadly. The 0.29.2 (today's release) supports Android Nougat, but as of the current release, it doesn't support split screen.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running an LG G3 with Fulmics 4.2. PoGO works fine in split screen mode, although it was designed to run in portrait mode, so I like to expand it (shrinking the other app) when capturing a Pokemon.